# python baserequesthandler client address is real established ip?

Tags: python, socketserver

i have a question for you

I'm using the udp socket server using baserequesthandler on python
I want to protect the server against spoofing - source address changes.

Does client_address is the actual ip address of established to server ?
If not, how do I get the actual address?

Answer (score 0):

Authenticate the packets so that you know that every message in session X from source address Y is from the same client.

By establishing a shared session key which is then used along with a sequence number to produce a hash of the packet keyed by the (sequence, session_key) pair. Which is then included in every packet. This can be done in both directions protecting both the client and server.

When you receive a packet you use its source address and the session number  to look up the session, then you compute HMAC((sequence, session_key), packet) and check if the MAC field in the message matches. If it doesn't discard the message.

This might not be a correct protocol but it is close enough to demonstrate the principle.